# Recursive Programming in Tcl for Permutations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tcl, permutation

I have an unknown pattern, and an unknown amount of data given to my getCombos proc.

I need to find a way to recursively produce as many matches in the data as the pattern permits.

For Instance:

```
# pattern  | data
# {0 1 2}    {0 {{A B C} {AA BB CC}}\
              1 {{D E F} {DD EE FF}}\
              2 {{G H I} {GG HH II}}\
             }
# returns this list: (split out on multiple lines are for your viewing pleasure)
  { A  E  I  }\
  { A  E  II }\
  { A  EE I  }\
  { A  EE II }\
  { AA E  I  }\
  { AA E  II }\
  { AA EE I  }\
  { AA EE II }\
```

The data will always be a dictionary list where the keys go from 0 to n.

The pattern will always be some mixture of 0 to n ( in this case {0 1 2} or {2 0 1} or the like).

This the reason I don't think I'll be able to use simple recursion - because I don't know how many elements will be in pattern, nor do I know how many elements will be in each value under data, nor do I know how many keys in data there will be.

The only thing I do know is that the number of elements inside an element of a data value match the number of elements in the pattern (eg. `[llength {0 1 2}]` is 3 and `[llength {A B C}]` is 3) which is very important because I'm pulling data from `$data` in that order.

Allow me to give a counterexample to highlight the way the pattern affects it:

```
# pattern  | data
# {1 2 1}    {0 {{A B C} {AA BB CC}}\
              1 {{D E F} {DD EE FF}}\
              2 {{G H I} {GG HH II}}\
             }
# returns this list: (split out on multiple lines are for your viewing pleasure)
  { D  H  F  }\
  { D  H  FF }\
  { D  HH F  }\
  { D  HH FF }\
  { DD H  F  }\
  { DD H  FF }\
  { DD HH F  }\
  { DD HH FF }\
```

As you can see in the example above `[dict get $data 0]` never entered the equation whatsoever. The first index of pattern corresponds to the first item in the first grouping in the list of values (A AA D DD G and GG) the second matches the second (B BB E EE H or HH) and the third matches the third (C CC F FF I or II). The actual value of those indexes match the key that should be used.

And in the end I need every combinations of the appropriate data according to the pattern.

Quite confusing. Here's the path I've been going down but as you can see I'm far from having anything valuable:

```
proc getCombo {pattern data} {
  set g yes
  set i 0  ;# These counters must be replaced by recursive design
  set j 0
  set k 0
  set p 0
  while {$g} {
    puts [lindex [lindex [dict get $data $i] $j] [lindex $pattern $p]]
    puts " [lindex [lindex [dict get $data $j] $k] [lindex $pattern $p]]"
    if {$k == [llength [dict get $data $i]] } {
      set k 0
      set g no
    }
    if {$j == [llength [dict get $data $i]] } {
      set j 0
      incr k
      incr p
    }
    incr j
  }
#########################
  for {set z 0} {$z < [llength [dict get $data 0]]} {incr z} {
    for {set o 0} {$o < [llength [dict get $data 1]]} {incr o} {
      for {set t 0} {$t < [llength [dict get $data 2]]} {incr t} {
        for {set p 0} {$p < [llength $pattern]} {incr p} {
        }
      }
    }
  }
########################
  #foreach pat $pattern {
    foreach key [dict keys $data] {
    }
  #}
########################
  #return $newdata
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do here? Its taken me all day to come up with the above code and I don't feel any closer, but I now have a feeling that my proc needs to be recursive if I'm going to produce what I want.

Thanks for any advice or direction you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**

Below gives you the subset in your example.

```
set input {
  {1 2 1}
  {
    0 {{A B C} {AA BB CC}}
    1 {{D E F} {DD EE FF}}
    2 {{G H I} {GG HH II}}
  }
}

set pattern [lindex $input 0]
set data [lindex $input 1]

proc perm {pattern data {start 0} {result ""}} {

  set len [llength $pattern]
  set rlen [llength $result]

  if {$rlen == $len} {
    puts [join $result "\t"]
    return
  }

  for {set i $start} {$i < $len} {incr i} {
    set k [lindex $pattern $i]
    foreach {subset} [dict get $data $k] {
      set temp $result
      lappend temp [lindex $subset $rlen]
      perm $pattern $data [expr {$i + 1}] $temp
    }
  }
}

perm $pattern $data
```

output:

```
D   H   F

D   H   FF

D   HH  F

D   HH  FF

DD  H   F

DD  H   FF

DD  HH  F

DD  HH  FF
```

**full perm**

```
set input {
  {1 2 1}
  {
    0 {{A B C} {AA BB CC}}
    1 {{D E F} {DD EE FF}}
    2 {{G H I} {GG HH II}}
  }
}

set pattern [lindex $input 0]
set data [lindex $input 1]

proc perm {pattern data {start 0} {result ""}} {

  set len [llength $pattern]

  if {[llength $result] == $len} {
    puts [join $result "\t"]
    return
  }

  for {set i $start} {$i < $len} {incr i} {
    set k [lindex $pattern $i]
    foreach {subset} [dict get $data $k] {
      foreach {value} $subset {
        set temp $result
        lappend temp $value
        perm $pattern $data [expr {$i + 1}] $temp
      }
    }
  }
}

perm $pattern $data
```

Output:

```
D   G   D

D   G   E

D   G   F

D   G   DD

D   G   EE

D   G   FF

D   H   D

D   H   E

D   H   F

D   H   DD

D   H   EE

D   H   FF

D   I   D

D   I   E

D   I   F

D   I   DD

D   I   EE

D   I   FF

D   GG  D

D   GG  E

D   GG  F

D   GG  DD

D   GG  EE

D   GG  FF

D   HH  D

D   HH  E

D   HH  F

D   HH  DD

D   HH  EE

D   HH  FF

D   II  D

D   II  E

D   II  F

D   II  DD

D   II  EE

D   II  FF

E   G   D

E   G   E

E   G   F

E   G   DD

E   G   EE

E   G   FF

E   H   D

E   H   E

E   H   F

E   H   DD

E   H   EE

E   H   FF

E   I   D

E   I   E

E   I   F

E   I   DD

E   I   EE

E   I   FF

E   GG  D

E   GG  E

E   GG  F

E   GG  DD

E   GG  EE

E   GG  FF

E   HH  D

E   HH  E

E   HH  F

E   HH  DD

E   HH  EE

E   HH  FF

E   II  D

E   II  E

E   II  F

E   II  DD

E   II  EE

E   II  FF

F   G   D

F   G   E

F   G   F

F   G   DD

F   G   EE

F   G   FF

F   H   D

F   H   E

F   H   F

F   H   DD

F   H   EE

F   H   FF

F   I   D

F   I   E

F   I   F

F   I   DD

F   I   EE

F   I   FF

F   GG  D

F   GG  E

F   GG  F

F   GG  DD

F   GG  EE

F   GG  FF

F   HH  D

F   HH  E

F   HH  F

F   HH  DD

F   HH  EE

F   HH  FF

F   II  D

F   II  E

F   II  F

F   II  DD

F   II  EE

F   II  FF

DD  G   D

DD  G   E

DD  G   F

DD  G   DD

DD  G   EE

DD  G   FF

DD  H   D

DD  H   E

DD  H   F

DD  H   DD

DD  H   EE

DD  H   FF

DD  I   D

DD  I   E

DD  I   F

DD  I   DD

DD  I   EE

DD  I   FF

DD  GG  D

DD  GG  E

DD  GG  F

DD  GG  DD

DD  GG  EE

DD  GG  FF

DD  HH  D

DD  HH  E

DD  HH  F

DD  HH  DD

DD  HH  EE

DD  HH  FF

DD  II  D

DD  II  E

DD  II  F

DD  II  DD

DD  II  EE

DD  II  FF

EE  G   D

EE  G   E

EE  G   F

EE  G   DD

EE  G   EE

EE  G   FF

EE  H   D

EE  H   E

EE  H   F

EE  H   DD

EE  H   EE

EE  H   FF

EE  I   D

EE  I   E

EE  I   F

EE  I   DD

EE  I   EE

EE  I   FF

EE  GG  D

EE  GG  E

EE  GG  F

EE  GG  DD

EE  GG  EE

EE  GG  FF

EE  HH  D

EE  HH  E

EE  HH  F

EE  HH  DD

EE  HH  EE

EE  HH  FF

EE  II  D

EE  II  E

EE  II  F

EE  II  DD

EE  II  EE

EE  II  FF

FF  G   D

FF  G   E

FF  G   F

FF  G   DD

FF  G   EE

FF  G   FF

FF  H   D

FF  H   E

FF  H   F

FF  H   DD

FF  H   EE

FF  H   FF

FF  I   D

FF  I   E

FF  I   F

FF  I   DD

FF  I   EE

FF  I   FF

FF  GG  D

FF  GG  E

FF  GG  F

FF  GG  DD

FF  GG  EE

FF  GG  FF

FF  HH  D

FF  HH  E

FF  HH  F

FF  HH  DD

FF  HH  EE

FF  HH  FF

FF  II  D

FF  II  E

FF  II  F

FF  II  DD

FF  II  EE

FF  II  FF
```

Comment: very close, I'm going through the code now to modify it to display only what I want, it's a little too robust, I only want a subset of this list. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LegitStack I submitted and update that gives the subset in your example.